# How can I restore "Open With" context menu item in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I tried various way to fix this problem but ended up with a dead end. My problem would be the missing "Open With" context menu items (or subitems?). It did not appear even though I hovered it for a minutes or two. Below is a screenshot of the respective right-click menu.

Note: The only problem with "Open With" is at the right-click menu (as well as FILE menu).

[image: Missing "Open With" context submenu]

---

Edited:

The "Open With" context submenu that only accessible at the top, while the typical right click menu doesn't work.

*Repaste from Comment.*

I don't think it's involved with any windows files because other user in the same computer doesn't affected at all. I can see the "Open With" context submenu. I believe this must have involved with current user's registry. It happens to all files (any file types, except folder). I can only use Open With by clicking at the file and select it manually at the top of Explorer window. (Refer to the link for the screenshot)

[image: The Open With that work only at the top of the window]

Comment: Try holding down the shift key when you right click.

Comment: Still same. I've tried with SHIFT, CTRL, ALT (not gonna work).

Comment: What skinning software are you using? Does the other user account have it installed as well?

Comment: Every user applied it by default. It's a CustoPack. I've been using it long time and the context menu disappeared recently. It means, there must be a registry problem, because I can use other user without the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt always show, if your file type is unknown or unassociated with an installed program it wont show.

Have you checked with any other files?

You could try running cmd and [using sfc/scannow](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) to see if any windows files have been adjusted.

Comment: It happened to all filetypes, even the common one (associated). SFC won't work because other user face no problem (in the same computer)

Answer (score 0):

One of the open-with thingies is b0rked.

Use https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/open_with_view.html to figure out which one it is (by disabling a bunch of them and checking if that fixed it).